# Trouble establishing a simple connection with JDBC to MySql, java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I fail to establish a connection to a MySql database on an external server when I use the mysql-connector-java version 8.0.11+ (I was currently testing with 8.0.25). However I am able to create a connection when I use the older MySql connector mysql-connector-java version 5.1.49.
The version of the MySql Database is "8.0.25-15"

The code fails on the first line:

```
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
{...}
```

Since I can connect though mysql-connector-java version 5.1.49, I first thought I could solve this problem by adding parameters to the DB_URL. I have experimented with a lot of parameters, but no luck:

```
useSSL=false
serverTimezone=GMT
useUnicode=true
characterEncoding=utf-8
passwordCharacterEncoding=utf-8
connectionCollation=utf8mb4_bin
autoReconnect=true
failOverReadOnly=false
maxReconnects=10
cacheServerConfiguration=false
```

The error I always receive is:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.toUpperCase(java.util.Locale)" because "javaEncoding" is null
    at com.mysql.cj.CharsetMapping.getMysqlCharsetForJavaEncoding(CharsetMapping.java:552)
    at com.mysql.cj.CharsetMapping.getCollationIndexForJavaEncoding(CharsetMapping.java:585)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeServerSession.configureCharacterSets(NativeServerSession.java:452)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1329)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:866)
```

A month ago, I did not have this problem, so I suspect the cause is a change in the database (I am not tbe database Administrator).
When I debug, the error seems to be caused because the program requests the "character_set_system" variable from MySql, which is"utf8mb3" (instead "utf8" or "utf8mb4").
I suspect that changing the database variable "utf8mb3" to "utf8" might solve this problem? But I am not certain and I cannot simply change this value because the database is hosted by an external company. I have typed "Show Variables" and "Show Global Variables" in a MySql editor for your information:
[A screenshot of the DB variables concerning language.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFevT.png)

Alternatively I would like to tell java to ignore "character_set_system". It seems that Java first looks for "local.character_set_results", but this variable returns null despite that "character_set_results" is defined in the database.

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Kind Regards

Steven

Comment: There are several things that need to be clarified here. For example, what is the database server's version. What is the actual database driver version you are using. What Java version are you currently running. Please provide this information in order to help in troubleshooting.

Comment: I am using JDK 16.
The database on the server has version: 8.0.25-15
I must clarify that the "mysql-connector-java" I mention in my post is the driver. So it works with older drivers (till version 5.1.49), But it no longer works with the newer drivers 8.0.11+ (I was currently testing with 8.0.25).